# ¿Cómo puedo fijar un fondo animado creado con div?

Tags: html, css, animación, fondo, animacion-css

tengo este fondo animado sacado de [esta página](https://animatedbackgrounds.me/wave.html) que lo quiero utilizar para que sea el fondo de toda mi página, es decir, quiero colocarle los contenedores de información por encima del fondo. El problema es que no sé cómo hacer para que se quede fijo y por debajo de todo. Intento poner algo simple como un título para iniciar, pero todo lo que hago siempre aparece al final de todo el fondo, y no es lo que quiero. Sé que la pregunta quizás sea medio simple, pero no consigo cómo hacerlo bien. Si alguien pudiera ayudarme, sería de ayuda.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid fondo">
    <div class="row-1 row"></div>
    <div class="row-2 row"></div>
    <div class="row-3 row"></div>
    <div class="row-4 row"></div>
    <div class="row-5 row"></div>
    <div class="row-6 row"></div>
    <div class="row-7 row"></div>
    <div class="row-8 row"></div>
    <div class="row-9 row"></div>
    <div class="row-10 row"></div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid contenedor">
    <h1>Título</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import "compass/css3";

.container-fluid.fondo{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.fondo > .row {
  background: #fffdf7;;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  animation: fade 5s infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  margin: 0;
}
.fondo > .row-2 {
  animation-delay:0.5s;
  margin: 0;
}
.fondo > .row-3 {
  animation-delay:1s;
  margin: 0;
}
.fondo > .row-4 {
  animation-delay:1.5s;
  margin: 0;
}
.fondo > .row-5 {
  animation-delay:2s;
  margin: 0;
}
.fondo > .row-6 {
  animation-delay:2.5s;
  margin: 0;
}
.fondo > .row-7 {
  animation-delay:3s;
  margin: 0;
}
.fondo > .row-8 {
  animation-delay:3.5s;
  margin: 0;
}

.fondo > .row-9 {
  animation-delay:4s;
  margin: 0;
}
.fondo > .row-10 {
  animation-delay:4.5s;
  margin: 0;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from { background: #fffdf7; }
  to { background: #71a5de }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes ponerle a tu *div* contenedor una posición absoluta que se traslape con la del div que tiene la animación, por ejemplo:

```css
@import "compass/css3";

.container-fluid.fondo{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.fondo > .row {
  background: #fffdf7;;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  animation: fade 5s infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  margin: 0;
}
.fondo > .row-2 {
  animation-delay:0.5s;
  margin: 0;
}
.fondo > .row-3 {
  animation-delay:1s;
  margin: 0;
}
.fondo > .row-4 {
  animation-delay:1.5s;
  margin: 0;
}
.fondo > .row-5 {
  animation-delay:2s;
  margin: 0;
}
.fondo > .row-6 {
  animation-delay:2.5s;
  margin: 0;
}
.fondo > .row-7 {
  animation-delay:3s;
  margin: 0;
}
.fondo > .row-8 {
  animation-delay:3.5s;
  margin: 0;
}

.fondo > .row-9 {
  animation-delay:4s;
  margin: 0;
}
.fondo > .row-10 {
  animation-delay:4.5s;
  margin: 0;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from { background: #fffdf7; }
  to { background: #71a5de }
}

.contenedor {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
}


h1 {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  padding: 10px; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid fondo">
    <div class="row-1 row"></div>
    <div class="row-2 row"></div>
    <div class="row-3 row"></div>
    <div class="row-4 row"></div>
    <div class="row-5 row"></div>
    <div class="row-6 row"></div>
    <div class="row-7 row"></div>
    <div class="row-8 row"></div>
    <div class="row-9 row"></div>
    <div class="row-10 row"></div>
</div>
<div class="contenedor">
  <h1>Título</h1>
</div>
```

He puesto el ejemplo en un *snippet*, puedes probarlo aquí mismo haciendo clic en el botón *Ejecutar*.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Me ha ayudado mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Soy algo nuevo por lo que quizá mi respuesta no sea la mejor solución pero logré hacerlo de esta forma:

1ro.- En el código HTML introduje el div que contiene el texto título dentro del "container-fluid fondo"

```
<div class="container-fluid fondo">

  <div class="row-1 row"></div>
  <div class="row-2 row"></div>
  <div class="row-3 row"></div>
  <div class="row-4 row"></div>
  <div class="row-5 row"></div>
  <div class="row-6 row"></div>
  <div class="row-7 row"></div>
  <div class="row-8 row"></div>
  <div class="row-9 row"></div>
  <div class="row-10 row"></div>
  <div class="contenedor"> <!-- Este lo he movido dentro-->
  <h1>Título</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Luego, en el código CSS he agregado lo siguiente:

1ro.- A la clase 'container-fluid fondo' le agregué un 'display:flex' para poder mover el titulo individualmente utilizando los flexbox, y además le agregué un flex-direction:column para que la animación del fondo se visualice correctamente

2do.- Un position:absolute a la clase contenedor (afecta únicamente al texto 'título' y de esta forma queda sobre la animación del fondo.

En conclusión, si creas un nuevo elemento y quieres que quede sobre el fondo deberás agregarle un position:absolute en CSS, en tu código HTML el nuevo elemento debe ir dentro del contenedor que posee la animación del fondo.

```
@import "compass/css3";

.container-fluid.fondo{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.fondo > .row {
  background: #fffdf7;;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  animation: fade 5s infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  margin: 0;
}
.fondo > .row-2 {
  animation-delay:0.5s;
  margin: 0;
}
.fondo > .row-3 {
  animation-delay:1s;
  margin: 0;
}
.fondo > .row-4 {
  animation-delay:1.5s;
  margin: 0;
}
.fondo > .row-5 {
  animation-delay:2s;
  margin: 0;
}
.fondo > .row-6 {
  animation-delay:2.5s;
  margin: 0;
}
.fondo > .row-7 {
  animation-delay:3s;
  margin: 0;
}
.fondo > .row-8 {
  animation-delay:3.5s;
  margin: 0;
}

.fondo > .row-9 {
  animation-delay:4s;
  margin: 0;
}
.fondo > .row-10 {
  animation-delay:4.5s;
  margin: 0;
}

.contenedor {
  color: rgb(252, 116, 116);
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: flex-start;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from { background: #fffdf7; }
  to { background: #71a5de }
}
```

Espero que te haya ayudado aunque sea un poco :)

Comment: Esta versión también me funciona, muchas gracias